# I can't post and redirect to payment gateway via PHP-Curl

Tags: php, database, payment-gateway, payment-processing, php-curl

I have built a form that requires the info ,including `$amount`.

Supposedly , the form will post the info to the MYSQL Db for storing . 
 `<form name="payFormCcard"  action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">`

For the PHP part , some payment info(e.g. `$amount` ,some info will be posted in hard coded form ) will post to Payment Gateway via Curl. And I will redirect to the Payment Gateway compulsorily `header("Location:https://test.paydollar.com/b2cDemo/eng/payment/payForm.jsp");`

Now , the data can save into the DB successfully .Although it goes to the Payment Gateway at the end ,the data cannot post to the Gateway .

> > One the Gateway site ,
>
> Error Message
>
> > Parameter merchantId Incorrect

Hence , sth is wrong on the Curl method .All parameters cannot pass to the payment Gateway successfully .

PHP Part in the `create.php`:

```
// Processing form data when form is submitted
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Validate name
    $input_CName = trim($_POST["CName"]);
    if (empty($input_CName)) {
        $CName_err = "Please enter a name.";
    } elseif (!filter_var(trim($_POST["CName"]), FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array("options" => array("regexp" => "/^[a-zA-Z'-.\s ]+$/")))) {
        $CName_err = 'Please enter a valid name.';
    } else {
        $CName = $input_CName;
    }
....Other field validation ...

....Storing to DB if every field is okay .
  if (empty($CName_err) && empty($Address_err) && empty($amount_err) && empty($Phone_err)) {
        // Prepare an insert statement
        $pdo = Database::connect();
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO donation (CName, Address, Phone, Amount ,Ticket, Purpose) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ? ,?, ?)";

        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($CName, $Address, $Phone, $amount ,$Ticket ,$Purpose));
        Database::disconnect();

Curl Part ......

$fields = array(
   'amount' => $amount,
      'merchantId'   => 'sth',
            'orderRef'    => 'sth',
            'currCode'   => '344',
            'mpsMode'    => 'NIL',
       'successUrl' =>'http://www.yourdomain.com/Success.html',
 'failUrl' =>'http://www.yourdomain.com/Fail.html',
'cancelUrl'=>'http://www.yourdomain.com/Cancel.html',
            'payType'    => 'N',
            'lang'       => 'E',
            'payMethod'  => 'CC',
            'secureHash'=> 'sth'
);

// build the urlencoded data
$postvars = http_build_query($fields);
    $ch = curl_init();
//
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://test.paydollar.com/b2cDemo/eng/payment/payForm.jsp");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,  count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postvars);
//
//// receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

   header("Location:https://test.paydollar.com/b2cDemo/eng/payment/payForm.jsp"); 
}

}
?>
```

Comment: You are capturing the server output into a var, but you aren't doing anything with it.  Are you supposed to pass a token or anything on your location redirect?

Comment: @ivanivan I am capturing some var in the form .I post the var and some hard-coded info via curl to the payment gateway .Lastly , I compulsory open the Epayment Gateway site .

Comment: The error is very straightforward. Your merchantID is wrong. You should ask the payment gateway provider for help with regards to the problem with your merchantID.

Comment: @hungryKoala I called the provider .They said some problems have happened in the set of parameters  .I guess the payment gateway has not received the data well .It 's because this set of parameters worked with the method of hidden input  form .

Comment: looking at the docs (http://www.paydollar.com/pdf/paygate_integration_guide.pdf ) i can see where a POST requires many more parameters, and returns info you probably want like the bank confirmation code.  are you simply duplicating what you have/had in a html form?

Comment: Also, try setting a header for Content-Type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` on your cURL command

Comment: @ivanivan Yes , I just simplify the duplicated parameters .I should have added enough parameters .That's why I can do it successfully in the method of hidden input .

Comment: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` Can you be specific on which lines ?